# Return pointer of class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, unordered-map

I have to return pointer to a class in a fuction

```
Contact* PhoneBook::SearchById(unsigned int id) {
    if (contacts_.find(id) != contacts_.end()) {
        return &(contacts_[id]);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Here are classes definitions:

```
struct Contact {
public:
    friend class PhoneBook;
private:
    Number number_;
    Name name_;
    Address address_;
    Contact(string number, string name, const string* address);
    string GetUnifiedNumber() const;
    std::vector<string> GetUnifiedName() const;
};
class PhoneBook {
public:
    unsigned int AddContact(string number, string name, const string* address = nullptr);
    Contact* SearchById(unsigned int id);
    PhoneBook();
private:
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, Contact> contacts_;
};
```

I get an error when compile

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/unordered_map:46,
                 from phone_book.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {const unsigned int&}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes1 = {0}; _Args2 = {}; long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {}; _T1 = const unsigned int; _T2 = Contact]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1657:63:   required from ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {const unsigned int&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const unsigned int; _T2 = Contact]’
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const unsigned int&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>, false>]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>; _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const unsigned int&>, std::tuple<>}; _Tp = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>, false>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>, false> >]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2082:36:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type* std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::_M_allocate_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::piecewise_construct_t&, std::tuple<const unsigned int&>, std::tuple<>}; _NodeAlloc = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>, false> >; std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>, false>]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:711:8:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = unsigned int; _Pair = std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact> >; _Equal = std::equal_to<unsigned int>; _H1 = std::hash<unsigned int>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type = Contact; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::key_type = unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unordered_map.h:977:20:   required from ‘std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = unsigned int; _Tp = Contact; _Hash = std::hash<unsigned int>; _Pred = std::equal_to<unsigned int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact> >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Contact; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = unsigned int]’
phone_book.cpp:109:39:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1668:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘Contact::Contact()’
         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
                                                                      ^
phone_book.cpp:113:1: note: candidate: ‘Contact::Contact(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, const string*)’
 Contact::Contact(string number, string name, const string* address) {
 ^~~~~~~
phone_book.cpp:113:1: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
phone_book.cpp:33:8: note: candidate: ‘Contact::Contact(const Contact&)’
 struct Contact {
        ^~~~~~~
phone_book.cpp:33:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
phone_book.cpp:33:8: note: candidate: ‘Contact::Contact(Contact&&)’
```

According to this I have to make another constructor, so I did. But compiler says it has to be public, and I don't want to make Contact constructor public. I want that Contacts can be created only by PhoneBook class. How can I solve this compilation problem?

Comment: there is no point to use`struct Contact `. cant you make it a class instead?

Comment: Yes I can. But it doesn't change anything, same error

Comment: You should use a map of <unsigned int, Contact *> if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `operator[]` of `std::map`, the value must be default constructible. Try adding a public constructor without arguments to your `Contact` class. You could also try to avoid usage of the operator:

```
Contact* PhoneBook::SearchById(unsigned int id) {
    auto c = contacts_.find(id);
    if (c != contacts_.end()) {
        return &c->second;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `contacts_` is a `std::map`.
You can pass copies of map items.
You can pass *iterators* of map items.

The `operator[]` does not work the same with a `std::map` as it does with an array.  The `operator[]` method is a search function.  See [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

So, the expression `&contacts[i]` for a `std::map` doesn't function the same as an array.

My suggestion is to change the signature of the function:

```
bool Phonebook::SearchById(int id, Contact& c)
{
  const std::map<unsigned int, Contact>::const_iterator iter = contacts_.find(id);
  if (iter != contacts_.end())
  {
     c = iter->second;
  }
  return iter != contacts_.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it has been noted, map operator [] searchs for item and create it if item is not found. The default public constructor is required for that. If you use *contacts_.find* approach the class instances are already created and constructor is not required so it works well.
But how *contacts_* can be filled? I suppose it should be the same issue of public default constructor. The solution can be

```
friend struct std::pair<const unsigned int, Contact>;
```

directly after

```
friend class PhoneBook;
```

That allows access to constructor for *pair* which is used in map and responsible for instance creation. But you grant access to constructor for one more class...

Alternatively (i.e. the friend is only PhoneBook) you can use pointer or smart pointer to keep contacts:

```
std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<Contact> > contacts_;
```

The negative is you need to create instances of *Contact* manually since *contacts_[ID]* can create only empty pointer which needs to be filled.

Please remember usage of *friend* is symptom that you need to redesign classes.